One Eternity Later (Frog Edition)
Ah, yes. It's been 518131871275444637960845131776 seconds. My beloved toad Macbeth has finally done it! I am so proud!


The above animation shows a frog jumping to a sequence of lilypads
Here are the coordinates of the lilypads the frog jumped to:
(8, 2)(9, 1)(8, 2)(10, 2)(3, 1)(7, 2)(8, 2)(2, 1)(4, 2)(1, 2)(7, 2)(5, 2)(4, 2)(10, 2)(8, 2)(10, 2)(3, 1)(3, 1)(2, 2)(10, 2)(5, 1)
Why am I so proud?

Source of artwork: https://www.gameartguppy.com/shop/frog-lilypad/

Is it because

 he has finally written a passage of Shakespeare?


 If we look at the grid one can see that we are dealing with a Colemak keyboard in disguise.


 If we track the frogs jump over the keyboard we see that it says:


 EYE OF NEWT AND TOE OF FROG… this is a reference to the witches speech in the Shakespearean play of Macbeth?

Additional note:

 This is a reference to the Infinite Monkey Theorem


 The number is 26^21 and I am not sure if this is significant.

According to the OP:

 the number refers to the expected or average number of seconds it would take to form a given string of 21 letters, with every keystroke being random and taking exactly one second. ToadMac(beth) is also a rather construed hint towards Colemak.) –


Correct, well done! rot13(Lbh unir n fyvtug zvfgnxr va gur raq erfhyg, gur sebt fgneg ng gur "R" yvylcnq, fb vg'f "Rlr [...] sebt" Vg vf vaqrrq n ersrerapr gb gur vasvavgr zbaxrl gurberz naq gur ahzore ersref gb gur rkcrpgrq be nirentr ahzore bs frpbaqf vg jbhyq gnxr gb sbez n tvira fgevat bs 21 yrggref, jvgu rirel xrlfgebxr orvat enaqbz naq gnxvat rknpgyl bar frpbaq. GbnqZnp(orgu) vf nyfb n engure pbafgehrq uvag gbjneqf Pbyrznx.)
